# xmos internal compiler error in llvmgen.c?

Tags: c, compilation, embedded, xmos

I ported some code that I wrote in C to XC and as a result this is what I got as my build output.

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project camera_with_memory ****

xmake CONFIG=Debug all 
Creating dependencies for point.xc
Compiling point.xc
xcc1: internal compiler error
Failed in /build/swnb/autobuild/swview/MacOSX/build/sb/tools_xcc1_c_llvm/BackEnd/LLVM/llvmgen.c, line 9314
    isExpVar(d->components->u.dimension)
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
http://www.xmos.com/support
xmake[1]: *** [.build_Debug/src/point.xc.o] Error 1
xmake: *** [bin/Debug/camera_with_memory_Debug.xe] Error 2
```

What could cause this?  I'm real puzzled.  My C code is ~80 lines.  Here is the declaration:

```
int sort_by_col(int center_points[num_points][2], static const unsigned int num_points, 
    int col_idx[col_idx_size], static const unsigned int col_idx_size);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the compiler. It seems that you cannot declare a multidimensional array whose first dimension is a static const variable e.g.

```
void f(static const unsigned n) {
     unsigned a[n][2];
}
```

This should be allowed. For future reference, since this compiler is maintained by XMOS, you can report a bug to them here:

https://www.xmos.com/en/support/contact

This bug is evident in version 13.0.2 of the XMOS compiler.

Disclosure: I work for XMOS on the compiler, so will report this bug.

Comment: 3 1/2 years later, I'm seeing the same problem. I can't find a compiler bug list/errata sheet anywhere on the xmos.com site.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to eliminate this error.  However I think this is a bug.

Within my function I had this line of code:

```
int working_array[size_points][2]; // array for copying data points
```

By replacing this with these two lines: (and adjusting the rest of the code to work with two arrays instead of one)

```
int working_array_x[size_points]; // array for copying data points
int working_array_y[size_points]; // array for copying data points
```

I eliminated the error.